# setState in CWebUser and CUserIdenitity messed up in examples

Tags: php, yii

I saw several (almost equivalent) examples on how to extend `Yii::app()->user` information in Yii. Here is [one of them](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/6/how-to-add-more-information-to-yii-app-user/).

The code (as is):

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    private $_id;

    public function authenticate()
    {
        $user=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
        if($user===null)
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        else if($user->password!==md5($this->password))
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        else
        {
            $this->_id=$user->id;
            $this->setState('lastLoginTime', $user->lastLoginTime); // added property
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        return !$this->errorCode;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }
}
```

It is affirmed that after that we can access the `lastLoginTime` values as follows:

```
Yii::app()->user->lastLoginTime
```

The problem here is that we called `setState` for `$this`, which is **CUserIdentity**, whereas `Yii::app()->user` is **CWebUser**, and **CWebUser** does not have any references to **CUserIdentity** by default.

Both of them do indeed support storing additional properties by means of `setState` and retrieving them via `getState`, but first uses internal `_state` array, and the second writes all in `$_SESSION`.

So the question is - how can we write an extended info into one entity, and then read it from another? I don't see anything in Yii code that could provide this. It looks like an error in the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call login method which is  `Yii::app()->user->login()` you have to pass a useridentity object that basically means CWebuser does have a reference to useridentity

```
Yii::app()->user->login($userIdentity,$duration);
```

Comment: More strictly speaking, `login` invokes `$this->changeIdentity`, which copies all `states` array from identity into the user's state. I have somehow overlooked that. But user **does not** have a reference to identity.